# API PHP JSON imprimir

Tags: php

[image: ASÍ SE VE POR PANTALLA]En un archivo php tengo un foreach en el que almacena la URL de un JSON, a la hora de imprimirlo, no quiero que se imprima los objetos, se que es un if(), pero no se como plantearlo.

```
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$resp2 = json_decode($resp); 

    foreach($resp2->orders as $orden){

      foreach($orden as $key=> $item){

          echo($item);

          echo '*';

        echo '<br>'.'<br>'; 
      }

    }
```

Comment: Busca información sobre la función **is_object()** de PHP y aplica el `if` sobre el $item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considera que el error puede ocurrir no solamente con objetos, hay otros **tipos** que tampoco son imprimibles.

Una solución más universal en este caso podría ser verificar los tipos, para imprimir sólo aquellos que sean *imprimibles*.

Puedes valerte de la función [`gettype()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php), cuyos valores retornados son:

- `boolean`
- `integer`
- `double` (por razones históricas `double` es retornado en caso de un `float`, y no simplemente `float`)
- `string`
- `array`
- `object`
- `resource`
- `resource (closed)` a partir de PHP 7.2.0
- `NULL`
- `unknown type`

De esos valores, son no imprimibles: `object`, `array`, `resource` ...

Entonces puedes crear un array para discriminar, en el código lo llamaremos `$notPrintable`, y verificar si cada `$item` es o no imprimible usando `in_array` junto con `gettype`.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Tipos no imprimibles
$notPrintable= array('object','array', 'resource', 'resource (closed)');
// ...

        foreach($orden as $key=> $item){
            if (!in_array(gettype($item), $notPrintable)) {
                echo "$item*<br /><br />";
            }
        }
// ...
```

Comment: Oh muchas gracias!!